# Unpausing videos has an audio delay

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, nvidia-graphics-card, youtube

Since yesterday (After a NVIDIA Driver update and a somewhat weird issue with my monitor) I have been experiencing about a second of delay when unpausing a video. For both online videos on youtube, and locally stored videos on VLC Media Player.

The actual video (visuals) start immediately, but the audio is delayed by about a second. This only happens when I have the video paused for about 30 seconds or longer (whether the window in question remains focused or not does not seem to matter).

The audio and video do remain in-sync.

Edit:
The issue is both for full-screen and window-mode.

Specs:
i7-7700k
GTX 1060 - 6GB
16 GB DDR4

Comment: the same is happening for me, so did you ever find a solution?